# $.getJson callback function is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I am calling a JSP by passing parameters which outputs a valid JSON as response, but still the `$.getJson` callback function is not getting fired.
  JSP page output is

```
 { "data": [ [ [ 1258185480000,4.39], 
               [ 1258186020000,4.31],
               [ 1258184940000,4.39],
               [ 1258183560000,4.39]  ] ] }
```

The URL points to the JSP page

My **jquery** code is

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {   
  alert("before");
  $.getJson(URL,function(json){
            alert("hello");
          var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), json.data, options);
    });

 alert("after");
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function is [$.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback) and not `$.getJson`

Comment: I changed to getJSON and tried, still the callback did not get triggered. How to  validate json in firebug?   I verified in Jsonlint that the response from JSP is a valid JSON

Comment: Is your server sending the correct MIME type: `application/json` or `application/javascript`?

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: URL,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(results){
        alert("Success!");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});


I get a parse error when I use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON. The data I get back from JSP is  { "data": [ [ [ 1258185480000,4.39], 
               [ 1258186020000,4.31],
               [ 1258184940000,4.39],
               [ 1258183560000,4.39]  ] ] }

I have verified that the JSON is proper in jsonlint

Comment: @Santhosh, you need to set the proper Content-Type header in your JSP page. Please verify with FireBug that when you perform the request, the server sends `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Answer (score 11):

```
$.getJSON( URL, function(data) {
  alert("hello");
});
```

is nothing but a shorthand for ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: URL,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    alert("hello");
  }
});
```

BUT

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
> the request will usually fail silently ... For example, all strings
> represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be
> enclosed in double-quotes

source: [jquery.getjson docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: It makes sense to me: "if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently!"

Answer (score 3):

$.getJSON will not utilize a callback with out a proper JSON object to process.

Comment: A link to jQuery documentation would highly improve your answer (here it is : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: This Helped!  I am testing in chrome 64.0.3282.167.  I was really stuck because chrome was showing the call was made and had all the expected headers and format.

Then I saw this comment and thought I should find a linter for json.  Sure enough I found jsonlint.com and it shows a [failure](https://jsonlint.com/?json=%7B%27hello%27:%20%27world%27%7D)  It took a while to realize I had single quotes. The [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) dictates double quotes.  With this change $.getJOSN() worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent about two hours on this.  I found another post that discusses the difference between `$.getJSON` and `$.get` and how there really isn't any.  So I swapped out my `getJSON()` for `get()` and it worked.

(Also want to mention that I had also verified everything else was working by logging from the rails action and logging what I could from the javascript *outside* the callback function.)

Comment: I believe the different between $.getJSON and $.get is in the content type (JSON vs XML).

Comment: I am not sure about the difference but $.get did return the JSON object. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Also ensure with Firebug that you are getting valid JSON back from the server.

Comment: I changed to getJSON and tried, still the callback did not get triggered. How to validate json in firebug? I verified in Jsonlint that the response from JSP is a valid JSON

Comment: On the Net tab in Firebug you'll be able to see all of the requests/responses.

Comment: $.ajax(
{ 
type: "GET", url: URL, 
dataType: "json", 
success: function(results){ alert("Success!"); }, 
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
{ alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown); } 
});

I get a parse error when I use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON. 
The data I get back from JSP is 
{ "data": [ [ [ 1258185480000,4.39], [ 1258186020000,4.31], [ 1258184940000,4.39], [ 1258183560000,4.39] ] ] } 

I have verified that the JSON is proper in jsonlint. How to find what the parse error is ?

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery 3.4.1:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function (json) {
    console.log('Got JSON');
    console.log(json);

})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    alert("There has been an error. If the problem persists contact the customer service");
})
.always(function () {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

If you believe that the JSON is ok and you are using chrome try "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".

Comment: Great for debugging, although much more useful with `alert(err)` rather than the fixed error message.